# How can i get the sub-child menu from a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, menu

I have got a task to do horizontal menu from json file.By doing this i didn't get the subchild.
my json file is

```
var data = [{
    "menu":[
        {
            "MenuId":1,
            "MenuName":"Home",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":1,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":2,
            "MenuName":"New Transaction",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":2,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":3,
            "MenuName":"Portfolio",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":3,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":4,
            "MenuName":"Analytics",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":4,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":5,
            "MenuName":"Instructions",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":5,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":6,
            "MenuName":"Data Upload",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":6,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":7,
            "MenuName":"Administration",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":7,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":[
                {
                    "MenuId":8,
                    "MenuName":"Masters",
                    "MenuLink":null,
                    "Action":null,
                    "Controller":null,
                    "ParentID":7,
                    "SortOrder":1,
                    "ModuleId":null,
                    "Menus":[
                        {
                            "MenuId":10,
                            "MenuName":"Currency",
                            "MenuLink":"/Currencies/Index",
                            "Action":"Index",
                            "Controller":"Currencies",
                            "ParentID":8,
                            "SortOrder":1,
                            "ModuleId":null,
                            "Menus":{
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "MenuId":11,
                            "MenuName":"Country",
                            "MenuLink":"/Countries/Index",
                            "Action":"Index",
                            "Controller":"Countries",
                            "ParentID":8,
                            "SortOrder":2,
                            "ModuleId":null,
                            "Menus":{
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "MenuId":9,
                    "MenuName":"User Management",
                    "MenuLink":null,
                    "Action":null,
                    "Controller":null,
                    "ParentID":7,
                    "SortOrder":2,
                    "ModuleId":null,
                    "Menus":{
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
];
$(function() {
for(var i = 0, j = data[0].menu.length; i<j; i++) {
    var root_menu = data[0].menu[i];
    if(root_menu.hasOwnProperty("MenuId")) {
        $("#menu").append('<li><a href="#" class="parent-menu">' + root_menu.MenuName + '</a></li>');
        if(root_menu.hasOwnProperty("Menus") && root_menu.Menus.length > 0) {
            $("#menu").append("<li><ul class='child-list' id='menu_" + root_menu.MenuId + "'>");
            for(var n = 0, m = root_menu.Menus.length; n<m; n++) {
                var sub_menu = root_menu.Menus[n];
                if(sub_menu.hasOwnProperty("MenuId")) {
                    $("#menu_" + root_menu.MenuId).append("<li class='nav-child'>" + sub_menu.MenuName + "</li>");
                }
            }
            $("#menu").append("</li></ul>");
        }
    }
}
});
```

How can i get the sub child by using this json file? You can see my code from http://jsfiddle.net/JcU4G/9/  In this Administration menu has two sub menus and that submenu has another sub menu.In the fiddle you can see that the sub menu comes under Home. But actually i want that sub menu under Administration menu and these sub menu master contains another grand sub menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* get it by `data[0].menu` BUT the `data` variable is not JSON; it is an array. You need to get rid of the square brackets at the start and end of the variable.

Instead of:

```
var data = [{
  menu: [
    {
       'Menu1'
```

You want:

```
var data = {
  menu: [
    {
       'Menu1'
```

And now `data` is an object. From there, your `for` loop will iterate over the keys in the object instead of a count.

```
for(var key in data.menu) {
    var root_menu = data.menu[key];
```

I've updated your Fiddle; hopefully it's what you're looking for.

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/buUtB/1/

Comment: I guess everything was okay? Sorry, I wrote it this morning and completely forgot to come back to it. Good luck!

Comment: Mclnnis- Do you know about responsive design?

Comment: Yep, what do you need help with?

Comment: Have fun: (even more articles at the bottom) http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/ http://mediaqueri.es/

Comment: mediaqueri.es has hundreds of them..?

Answer (score 0):

You could to use a recursive function.

The code I am posting does not create a menu, it just logs to the console each menu name. It does however demonstrate how you need to iterate through the object. You'll need to replace the log code with code to render your menu.

```
for (var i in data[0].menu) {
    logMenu(data[0].menu[i]);
}

function logMenu(menuNode) {
    console.log(menuNode.MenuName);
    for (var i in menuNode.Menus) {
        logMenu(menuNode.Menus[i]);
    }
}
```

Notice that the function calls itself once for each sub-menu.

You'll probably need to pass a 'parent' parameter so you know which menu item each sub-menu item belongs to. If the 'parent' parameter is null then you know to create a new root menu element on the page, rather than a sub-menu element.

E.g.

```
for (var i in data[0].menu) {
    logMenu(data[0].menu[i], null);
}

function logMenu(menuNode, parent) {
    if (parent == null) {
        //Render root menu element in HTML
    } else {
        //Render sub menu element in HTML related to parent
    }
    for (var i in menuNode.Menus) {
        logMenu(menuNode.Menus[i], menuNode);
    }
}
```